# What is the ATC service advertised in Bonjour?

Tags: network, services, bonjour

While browsing for services in my local network with [Bonjour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)), I notice that my MacBook Pro provides the `_atc._tcp.` service. However I couldn't find a description for such a service from the [canonical list of macOS services](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1312/_index.html) nor inside the [DNS-SD registry](http://www.dns-sd.org/ServiceTypes.html).

The question is, what is that service? How to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_atc._tcp.` service is/was the Shared iTunes Library service.

I'm out and about at the moment, but when I get a chance I will update this answer with some sort of link/source to back this up.

**[EDIT]**

I haven't yet had a chance to have a thorough look for a source, although I did do a quick Google search and found a reference to the `_atc._tcp.` service at this MacRumors [discussion](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/stubborn-home-sharing-ios-problem.1689035/). In it you'll see the 10th comment (by priitv8) states:

> For comparison, I've included a screenshot from my Shared iTunes Library service (_atc._tcp.).

Also, it occurred to me that you may want to download [Bonjour Browser](http://www.tildesoft.com/) and see if that sheds any more light on this for you. It's an old app but works well (although I haven't used it in macOS Sierra - not sure what you're using).

As an aside, the list of [Bonjour service types used in Mac OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1312/_index.html) you linked to is **not an exhaustive list**. It was only a list of common Bonjour service types used in Mac OS X and hasn't been updated since July 2004.

Comment: I've been using Bonjour Browser; trying to identify a macOS computer from all others via its bonjour services (but that would be the subject of another question altogether).